# Show CSS focus on IFrame when tabbed to

Tags: html, css, iframe

In order to create a 508 compliant page I need to ensure that whenever I tab, the focus is visible on the correct item.  I have set the tab index of my iframe and am attempting to show visual focus when it is tabbed to in internet explorer.  I have tried the following:

```
iframe:focus {
    outline:2px dotted #000;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

but I don't see an outline.

How can I show an outline on my iframe when it is tabbed to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to apply your CSS to the body of the iframe's content, not the iframe, since its this content which actually gets focus.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112364

So if your iframe has a src of "test.html" then test.html would have a css class like this:

```
body {
    outline:2px dotted #000;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

You might need to play with that a bit, but it demonstrates the misconception here.

Comment: I tried a few variations assuming focus on body such as "iframe:focus body"   and   "iframe body:focus"   but neither are working when tabbing.

Comment: No, the CSS needs to be on the iframe page itself (ie the page referred to by the iframe with the "src" attribute), not the containing page.

Comment: I am attempting to add it to the iframe page itself as well, but I really don't know where the focus goes.  I tried saying body:focus and html:focus, but it seems to be on the document itself.