# (CSS iframe:focus) Is there a bug on w3schools.com?

Tags: javascript

I have read on w3schools.com that there is this default value in every browser:

```
iframe:focus { outline: none; }
```

So I tried to change it to

```
iframe:focus { outline: 10px solid red; }
```

Here is the example (You have to click the first button and then use tab to navigate to the iframe.):

```css
iframe:focus
{
  outline:10px solid red;
}

input:focus
{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="button1" />
<input type="button" value="button2" />
<iframe src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

As you can see, the iframe never gets a red outline. Thus the CSS is not working.
I also tried to set the focus using JavaScript .focus() and it also doesn't work.

It seems that an iframe can't get the focus. The same is said in [34157775](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157775/show-css-focus-on-iframe-when-tabbed-to).

So my question is: Why is there a default value for iframe:focus on w3schools.com if an iframe can't even get the focus? Is this a bug on w3schools.com?

Comment: I don't know about this particular issue, but as a general rule, please don't rely on `w3schools.com`. Even when their code works (which it does most of the time, to be fair), it shows examples of horrible and outdated practices. You're much better off with MDN for learning CSS and JS.

Comment: See https://allyjs.io/data-tables/focusable.is.html#iframe-element, escpecially the footnotes

Comment: If I use my element inspector and *force* the iframe state to `:focus`, I definitely do see the 10px red outline in your example. And my browser *does* by default set the outline to `none`, although I haven't been able to trigger the focus state either with content or without, with tabindex or a javascript event. At most, I get the activeElement state triggered. So in my opinion, no, it's not a bug on w3schools. It's just not very useful information in most cases.

Comment: What does the HTML/CSS specification say?